# Use Prolog to find the a list of employees that work in a specific company

Tags: prolog

```
employee (tom, shopify).
employee (eva, shopify).
employee (eva, ibm).
employee (sam, cisco).
employee (sam, bridgehead).
employee (jeff, ibm).
```

Using the setof predicate, we would like to get the list of ibm employees.
Write this query:

```
? - setof (????)

L = [eva, jeff]
```

Comment: What is the problem? Do you know how to write a query to get a single *ibm* worker? Do you know how tu use `setof`?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding [setof/3] (https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=setof/3) is the same as [bagof/3] (https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=bagof/3), but returns a sorted set instead.

```
?- setof(X, employee(X, ibm), L).
```